# Group by array object by object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, group-by

I have an array of object like that :

```
[{ name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Madrid' }, 
 { name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', city: 'Berlin' }],
```

And i would like group by the city, like below:

```
[{name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', cities: ['london', 'Paris']},
 {name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike',cities: ['Paris', 'Madrid']}, 
 {name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', cities: ['Berlin']}]
```

I try with this function by, I don't have the good array

```
let arrayPeople = [{ name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Madrid' }, 
 { name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', city: 'Berlin' }],

 let groups = {};
 for (let i = 0; i < arrayPeople.length; i++) {
   let groupName = arrayPeople[i].city;
   if (!groups[groupName]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
   }
   groups[groupName].push(arrayPeople[i].city);
 }
 let arrayGroupBy= [];
 for (let groupName in groups) {
   arrayGroupBy.push({ ...arrayPeople, cities: groups[groupName] });
 }
```

How I can make my group by ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Iterate over the array and create a map with a key for each person. What is `res`?

Comment: _"And i would like group by the city, like below:"_ No, you want to group the cities by person.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: my bad for 'res', I edited the code for replace ```res``` by '```arrayPeople```

Comment: @ThomasSablik: I don't know how use map for iterate on the city..

Comment: Your approach is pretty near to the correct solution. You are grouping persons by city. You have to turn around and group cities by person

Comment: @ThomasSablik: yes, but if i write : ``` var groupName = res[i].name;````, it's possible to group with 'name, hobby and age ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to process your input array, using the name, age and hobby as a key to create a grouping object, and adding the city for each key to an array in that object. You can then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to grab just the values from the grouping object into an array:

```js
let arrayPeople = [{ name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Madrid' }, 
 { name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', city: 'Berlin' }];
 
let arrayGroupBy = Object.values(arrayPeople.reduce((c, { city, ...rest }) => {
  let key = Object.values(rest).join('#');
  c[key] = c[key] || { ...rest, city : [] };
  c[key].city.push(city);
  return c;
}, {}));
console.log(arrayGroupBy);
```

Note the above code is dependent on the properties in the objects being in the same order in each object (in the sample data, `name`, `age`, `hobby`). If this might not be the case, you will need to create the key using the named properties instead, for example:

```js
let arrayPeople = [{ name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, 
 { age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', name: 'Mario', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Peter',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'Paris', age: '22' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Madrid' }, 
 { name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', city: 'Berlin' }];
 
let arrayGroupBy = Object.values(arrayPeople.reduce((c, { name, age, hobby, city}) => {
  let key = `${name}#${age}#${hobby}`;
  c[key] = c[key] || { name, age, hobby, city : [] };
  c[key].city.push(city);
  return c;
}, {}));
console.log(arrayGroupBy);
```

Note also that all the above code is dependent on choosing a delimiter (I've used `#`) that will not occur in the `name` or `hobby` values. If there is no suitable delimiter character, then it is safer to use something like [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to produce the `key` value e.g. for the second code block you would use:

```
let key = JSON.stringify([name, age, hobby]);
```

Comment: This answer working hinges on the fact that the objects in `arrayPeople`'s have their properties in exactly the same order, right?  If I change one of the objects and put, say, `age` first, this will break.  In TypeScript at least, there's no way to observe the order of object properties, so I'd consider making your `key` something that does not depend on such an ordering.

Comment: @jcalz you are absolutely correct, I've added a note about that to the answer and code which will work in that scenario. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This might seem like nitpicking, but I usually recommend escaping strings instead of just concatenating them, otherwise some wise guy could do something like `let arrayPeople = [ { name: 'Peter#22', age: 20, hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, { name: 'Peter', age: 22, hobby: '20#soccer', city: 'Paris' } ]` and mess it up.  My solution below uses `JSON.stringify([person.name, person.hobby, person.age])`, but there are lighter-weight alternatives. An injection attack is probably unlikely here, and the OP might not care, but I just wanted to point it out for future users with other use cases.

Comment: @jcalz "*This might seem like nitpicking*" (yeah, it is :) I've updated the answer with a note to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is pretty near to the correct solution. You are grouping persons by city. You have to turn around and group cities by person

```
let arrayPeople = [{ name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'london' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Peter', age: '22',  hobby: 'soccer', city: 'Paris' }, 
 { name: 'Mario', age: '30',  hobby: 'bike', city: 'Madrid' }, 
 { name: 'Rick', age: '28',  hobby: 'tennis', city: 'Berlin' }];

let groups = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arrayPeople.length; i++) {
  let groupName = arrayPeople[i].name;
  if (!groups[groupName]) {
   groups[groupName] = {name: arrayPeople[i].name, age: arrayPeople[i].age, hobby: arrayPeople[i].hobby, cities: []};
  }
  groups[groupName].cities.push(arrayPeople[i].city);
}
 
console.log(Object.values(groups));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is TypeScript so I'd probably come up with the type corresponding to the final array elements: that is, remove the `city` property and add a `cities` property:

```
type PersonCities = Omit<typeof arrayPeople[number], "city"> & { cities: string[] };
```

Then you want to put all your objects into a dictionary keyed by whatever you want the grouping condition to be (converted into a string):

```
const peopleCities: Record<string, PersonCities> = {};
for (let p of arrayPeople) {
  const { city, ...person } = p;
  const groupByKey = JSON.stringify([person.name, person.hobby, person.age]);
  if (!(groupByKey in peopleCities)) {
    peopleCities[groupByKey] = { ...person, cities: [] };
  }
  peopleCities[groupByKey].cities.push(city);
}
const arrayPeopleCities = Object.values(peopleCities);
```

Here we're making the grouping key a JSON string of the `name`, `hobby`, and `age` properties in an array.  And some object rest/spread syntax to copy people properties around without too much redundancy.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-F1vKTRAA0KAISCy3W20Op3p4jE2WgdmXeWKgjKlUl0nliR4XM2u2OhA4rkQHVa6PEVhIy7UbG4mt6GskuUNptWlsF9tagcSHt-CT8QUQ1OGMdmolSz6lsnnS7XG5CABWNLAWoAblBgH9LoKJ2WjxJN-jCahQFr1GxBXuZXrV9FSAA)